# Import Json data from url and save it to database laravel

Tags: json, laravel, import

i have this json data come from a url:

```
[
    {
    "id": "4070",
    "title": "Speedway Racing",
    "description": "Drivers start your engines! Professional oval track racing that explodes with stock car racing action!",
    "instructions": "Use WASD or Arrow keys to move the car ",
    "url": "https://html5.gamemonetize.com/b7dzsckxzmy5z3to54nif435exdiogkz/",
    "tags": "Car, Cars, Racing",
    "thumb": "https://img.gamemonetize.com/b7dzsckxzmy5z3to54nif435exdiogkz/512x384.jpg",
    "width": "960",
    "height": "600",
    "category": "Driving"
},]
```

I need to save all data in database but for category i need to create new category from the category fled and save it in post_categry table (cat_id, post_id) if his not exists, also check f this game exists in db if yes ignore if no save it.

My GameController:

the json data come from this lik:
[This link](https://gamemonetize.com/rssfeed.php?format=json&category=All&type=html5&company=All&amount=10)

```
 public function importer_start(Request $request)
    {
      $game_cat = new Game;
      $validatedata = $this->validate($request, [
        'game_source' => 'required',
        'source_url' => 'required|url',
      ]);
      $dataurl = $request->input('source_url');
      $sourve_name = $request->input('game_source');
      $content = file_get_contents($dataurl);
      $data = json_decode($content, true);
      $query_ammount = $request->input('source_url');
      parse_str($query_ammount, $params);
      $game_amount = $params['amount'];
      $query_ammount = $request->input('source_url');
      parse_str($query_ammount, $params);
      $game_amount = $params['amount'];

      $url = $request->input('source_url');
      $parmt_url = parse_url($url);
      parse_str($parmt_url['query'], $params);
      if ($params['format'] != 'json') {
        toastr()->error('Please select JSON file to import games');
        return redirect()->back();
      }
      if (@strpos($dataurl, Constants::GAMESOURCE_GAMEMONETIZE)) {
        $finalarray = array();
        foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
      // dd($value);
          array_push($finalarray,array(
              'game_id' => $value['id'],
              'title' => $value['title'],
              'description' => $value['description'],
              'instructions' => $value['instructions'],
              'url' => $value['url'],
              'category' => !empty($value['category']) ? $value['category']: 'uncategorized',
              'tags' => $value['tags'],
              'thumb' => $value['thumb'],
              'width' => $value['width'],
              'height' => $value['height'],
              'source' => Constants::GAMESOURCE_GAMEMONETIZE,
          'views' => 15,
          )
        );
}
$categories[] = $value['category'];
Game::insert($finalarray);
toastr()->success('You have add '.$game_amount.' from '.\Constants::GAMESOURCE_GAMEMONETIZE.'');
return redirect()->route('admin.importer');
      }elseif (@strpos($dataurl, Constants::GAMESOURCE_GAMEDISTRIBUTION)) {
    $result = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);
    $key = array_search('categoryList', array_column($result, 'categoryList'));
    $finalarray = array();
    foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
            array_push($finalarray,array(
          'title' => $value['title'],
          'gameType' => $value['gameType'],
          'gameMobile' => $value['gameMobile'],
          'mobileMode' => $value['mobileMode'],
          'instructions' => $value['instructions'],
          'description' => $value['description'],
          'width' => $value['width'],
          'height' => $value['height'],
          'url' => $value['url'],
          'source' => Constants::GAMESOURCE_GAMEDISTRIBUTION,
          'assetList' =>   json_encode($value['assetList']),
          'tagList' => json_encode($value['tagList']),
          'category' => $value['categoryList'][0]['name'],
          'views'=> 15,
      )
    );
        }
        //dd($finalarray);
        Game::insert($finalarray);
        toastr()->success('You have add '.$game_amount.' from '.\Constants::GAMESOURCE_GAMEDISTRIBUTION.'');
        return redirect()->route('admin.importer');
      }
    }
```

Laravel version: 7.0

Thank you for your helpe.

Comment: You can insert json to your table `$table->json('options');`

Comment: Yes but i need to store every data in his row in database to be able to edit hem after